# Subqueries in select statement to calculate sum

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, subquery, dql

I would like to represent the following SQL Query in Doctrine with Symfony 2.x:

```
SELECT (SELECT sum(J.amount) FROM journals as J WHERE debit_id = ?) - (SELECT   sum(J.amount) FROM gold.journals as J WHERE credit_id = ?)
```

I've spend some times with the querybuilder and then moved to DQL Query:

```
$q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT (SELECT sum(J.amount) FROM xxx\Entity\Journal as J WHERE debit = ?) - (SELECT sum(J.amount) FROM xxx\Entity\Journal as J WHERE credit = ?))');
```

which both lead into sort of Syntax exceptions:

```
Syntax Error] line 0, col 97: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '-'
```

Whats the best doctrine/symfony way to get this query running?

Comment: Why don't you get each sum by a separate query and subtract them after that. Your sql query is not valid

Comment: This would be my last solution. But i'm curious if there is a doctrine way to solve my issue...

Answer (score 2):

Oukay, found now the a solution:

```
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $x = $qb->select()
        ->addSelect('(SELECT sum(J1.amount) FROM xxx\Entity\Journal as J1 WHERE J1.debit = :id)')
        ->addSelect('(SELECT sum(J2.amount) FROM xxx\Entity\Journal as J2 WHERE J2.credit = :id)')
        ->from("xxx\Entity\Journal", "tmp")
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->setParameter('id', 1);

    return print_r($x->getQuery()->getArrayResult()[0],true);
```

Its a bit ugly cause it looks like the Query Builder NEEDS ->from() to be set to something... Thats why i've used the setMaxResults to limit the output. Its still not the perfect solution but well... I'ts a good point to start.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this method](http://www.philipphoffmann.de/blog/2012/08/29/a-bulletproof-pattern-for-creating-doctrine-subqueries-of-any-complexity/) for doing nested queries in Doctrine.

Comment: Looks like this tutorial is for doctrine prior to version 2.x... :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
$q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT 
    (
        (SELECT sum(J.amount) FROM xxx\Entity\Journal as J WHERE debit = ?) 
            - 
        (SELECT sum(J.amount) FROM xxx\Entity\Journal as J WHERE credit = ?)
    ) as total
');
```

And then get the scalar value of the query result.

```
$q->getQuery->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: Does not work for me :-/ [Syntax Error] line 0, col 32: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'